# using multiple Material UI Rating Component in single form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using 2 Rating components in a single form. No matter which rating I change, only the first component is getting updated. Demo.js is the root component and it is calling Rate1 and Rate2 which are two Rating components. I have tried using both of them in the same component, creating different onChange for both of them.

**Demo.js (main component)**

```
import React from 'react';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Rate1 from './Rate1'
import Rate2 from './Rate2'

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <Rate1/>
      <Rate2/>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Rate1.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

export default function Rate1() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = React.useState(2);
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
        <Typography component="legend">Controlled1</Typography>
        <Rating
          name="simple-controlled"
          value={value1}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setValue1(newValue);
          }}
        />
      </Box>
     
    </div>

  </>
  );
}
```

**Rate2.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

export default function Rate2() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
        <Typography component="legend">Controlled2</Typography>
        <Rating
          name="simple-controlled"
          value={value}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
        />
      </Box>
     
    </div>
  </>
  );
}
```

What I want is for both components to get updated separately. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are using same name for both components update that and it should work. Change the `name="simple-controlled"` to be different for both